# SQL Query to truncate to two decimal points?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a pretty big query at the moment and I am missing one element... I need to cut the data to two decimal points (no rounding needed). I Googled but have had trouble adapting it to the current query.

```
SELECT 
    FechaDeSistema, Code, 
    CASE 
        WHEN DR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN Cantidad 
    END as Debit, 
    CASE 
        WHEN CR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN Cantidad 
    END AS Credit, 
    CASE 
        WHEN DR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN BalanceDebito 
        WHEN CR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN BalanceCredito 
    END AS Balance 
FROM 
    Ledger 
WHERE 
    (Debito_Cuenta = @Acct) OR 
    (Credito_Cuenta = @Ncct) 
ORDER BY 
    FechaDeSistema DESC
```

I basically need to truncate the Credit and Debit "cases" (is that how you say that?) to two decimal points. How can I pull it off? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just cast it to a lower precision decimal, this will chop off the trailing digits.

```
cast(yourColumnName as decimal(19,2)) as desiredColumnName
```

More specifically to your query code

```
SELECT 
    FechaDeSistema, 
    Code, 
    CASE 
        WHEN DR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN cast(Cantidad as decimal(19,2)) 
    END as Debit, 
    CASE 
        WHEN CR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN cast(Cantidad as decimal(19,2)) 
    END AS Credit, 
    CASE 
        WHEN DR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN cast(BalanceDebito as decimal(19,2)) 
        WHEN CR_Socio = @SocioNum THEN cast(BalanceCredito as decimal(19,2)) 
    END AS Balance 
FROM Ledger 
WHERE (Debito_Cuenta = @Acct) 
OR    (Credito_Cuenta = @Ncct) 
ORDER BY FechaDeSistema DESC";
```

Comment: Well that was far easier than what I was trying to implement (some  massive mess). Thanks Evan!

Comment: gotta wait a min or two for me to approve the answer ;-)

Comment: No problem! Also added a cleaner Query version with the correct casting.

Comment: Any reason why it's "19"?

Comment: @DaoLam yes that's the decimal precision. So it supports 19 digits with 2 decimal places. 19 is fairly standard when working with decimal numbers.

Comment: everyone knows this is the best and fastest way to do ROUNDING!   this does NOT do truncation.  to truncate use the 3rd param of round() function set the param to true(1)  i.e.  ROUND(x, 2, 1)

Answer (score 8):

CASTing will round. If you really want to truncate you can use ROUND with the truncate option, like this..

```
DECLARE @MyNum DECIMAL(19,4) = 100.1294

SELECT @MyNum 'MyNum'
, CAST(@MyNum AS DECIMAL(19,2)) 'Cast will round'
, ROUND(@MyNum,2,4) 'Round with truncate option'
, CAST(ROUND(@MyNum,2,4) AS DECIMAL(19,2)) 'Better Truncate'
```

Comment: what does option (4)  do? i have always used option (1)   i.e. round(x, 2, 1) instead of round(x, 2, 4)